# What is the mean of the resulting measurement

Tags: self-study

The mean set of measurement is 90. A constant value is 12 is added to each measurement. What is the mean of the resulting measurement?

Comment: You've tagged this as self-study. What work have you already attempted to try and answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

102

$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i+12) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 12 = 90 + 12 = 102$

Comment: Please be cautious of providing complete answers to `[self-study]` questions. We provide hints only.  Our policies are described [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).